# nginx 404 redirection from second time

Tags: angular-ui-router, nginx-location

I'm implementing angular static application with ui-routes and nginx as a web server. My Angular routes code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: false,
  requireBase: false
});
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/views/homePage.html'
});
```

And nginx.conf

```
location / {
        root   html/MySite;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

When i type localhost in the browser address bar it is redirecting to my site home page and url will changing to http://locahost/home after this when refresh page page it will redirecting to nginx 404 page, and when i type http://locahost/home in address bar then also it is redirecting nginx 404 page.

Comment: http://locahost/home is a typo or source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx location should be like:

```
server {
server_name localhost;
root html/MySite;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
}
```

Then it will redirect to you index.html